# How to increase control procedure memory in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am trying to increase control procedure memory usage with following code:

```
match (n)-[e]->(m)
with collect(e) as edges
call super_awesome_module.do_something(edges) MEMORY UNLIMITED YIELD * RETURN *;
```

I get a following message `error:Client received exception: line 3:37 mismatched input 'MEMORY' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is missing the keyword `PROCEDURE`. Your Cypher query should look like this:

```
MATCH (n)-[e]->(m)
WITHcollect(e)AS edges
CALL super_awesome_module.do_something(edges)
PROCEDURE MEMORY UNLIMITED
YIELD *RETURN *;
```